# Why camera taking 2 copies at a time?

Tags: camera, 9.0-pie

I'm using Asus Zenfone Max Pro M2 with Android Pie. 
So when I take a shot from default camera it does saving two copies at a time. Same for front camera.

Answer (score 2):

Some cameras allow repeated captures if the button is depressed longer. See your manual for settings about the "Continuous Shot" setting, since it may be a form of "burst mode". My Samsung (sorry my experience is not with Zenfone) allows for "burst mode" to allow the camera itself to take a short burst of images, selecting its choice of "best", but keeps the others for any personal preference otherwise. Your phone may do similar.

Comment: I disable continuous shot but it is not working. Thanks for your time and efforts.